# Matrix Reporting Services Issue

Tags: sql, vb.net, reporting-services, matrix

I have a matrix with rows indicating a name (Ex Store name) and I have data pertaining to that in the DATA cells. I also have another date field in this format (`MM/DD/YYYY`). I would like to use a cross tab between Store Names and Just the Month of the date field.

```
                   Jan  Feb Mar Apr (From Date)
 A (Store Name)    10   5    3   2
 B                  3   4    2   1
```

is there any expression I can use to get the month format on the header of column.

thx.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:
    Select to_char(when,'MMM'), sum(what) from data group by to_char(when, 'MMM')

Answer (score 0):

The column group label for month needs to be the same as the column group.

Something like
=Fields!MyDateValue.ToString("MMM")